# using jQuery to get selected value from form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has a select field defined like this

The myName[] is like that because there are several repetitions in the sign-up form (the user first defines how many he wants to enter, and then that many forms are generated)

Now I would like to get the selected value using jQuery whenever somethign is selected, but as expected, it won't work: it's trying to get the info from an id, and there's more than one of this id. The result is that it's always getting the content of the first select field with the id it finds. I tried changing the id to a class, but that didn't work.

So how can I get the selected value of the select box that's actually triggering the event?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#idOfmyName').change(function() {
    var naam = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value');
    alert(naam);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="myname[]" id="idOfmyName">
  <option value="jack">Jack</option>
  <option value="rose">Rose</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's working on snippet.. what do you want anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use `$(this).val()`, if you want the selected Element?

But yes, when you've got multiple of the same ID, jQuery will over ever select the first one it finds - Though you do seem to know this; I've changed it to a class in this demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.idOfmyName').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="myname[]" class="idOfmyName">
  <option value="jack">Jack</option>
  <option value="rose">Rose</option>
</select>

<select name="myname[]" class="idOfmyName">
    <option value="harry">Harry</option>
    <option value="sally">Sally</option>
</select>

<select name="myname[]" class="idOfmyName">
    <option value="edward">Edward </option>
    <option value="vivian">Vivian </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

for multiple you can do something like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select name="myname[]" class="idOfmyName">
    <option value="jack">Jack</option>
    <option value="rose">Rose</option>
  </select>
 <select name="myname[]" class="idOfmyName">
 <option value="jack">Jack</option>
  <option value="rose">Rose</option>
 </select>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var names = [];
     $('.idOfmyName').change(function() {
    var naam = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value');
    if($.inArray(naam,names)){
       names.push(naam);
    }
    alert(names);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JavaScript way to get selected value using onchange method**

```js
function getSelectedValue(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

```html
<select name="myname[]" onchange="getSelectedValue(this.value)">
    <option value="jack">Jack</option>
    <option value="rose">Rose</option>
</select>

<select name="myname[]" onchange="getSelectedValue(this.value)">
    <option value="harry">Harry</option>
    <option value="sally">Sally</option>
</select>
```